# Step Through HTML in VS 2010?

Tags: javascript, html, visual-studio-2010

I'm wondering if it is possible to step through HTML and JavaScript Code in VS2010 ?  I have a project in which I have an HTML file with Javascript inside it...I can't set a breakpoint on the HTML and although I can set a breakpoint on the Javascript it will not pause when I run the project.

Thanks

Comment: You mean to say setting breakpoint in HTML code to debug itin VS2010?

Answer (score 1):

you can't debug HTML. If you want to debug javascript code that is embedded in the HTML, add a line

```
debugger;
```

inside the script tag. The browser will stop and let you debug it from there

Answer (score 0):

As far as i know, you can't set breakpoints in/on HTML code, why would you. You can step through JavaScript code in IE, if you allow debugging of client scripts in the internet options of IE. For any other browser you will need some other JavaScript-debugger, something like Firebug.

Answer (score 0):

If you are sure you have the javascript debugger attached, you can put a simple `debugger;` statement in your js which will cause it to break. You will have to have script debugging turned on an VS attached to your IE process. You could also use the IE Dev Tools JS debugger.